# How to disable Entity Framework auto join when querying from table with foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have these model classes:

```
[Table("db_course")]
public class Year
{
    public Guid YearId { get; set; }
    public string YearName { get; set; }
}

[Table("db_student")]
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set;}
    public string StudentName { get; set;}
    public Year StudentYear { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query the students without Entity Framework performing a join on these 2 tables to get the `StudentYear` for the student. I want that to be an option, not a default choice.

```
using (var context = new StackOverFlowContext()) 
{
    var students = context.Students                        
                          .Select(s => new Student 
                                       {
                                           StudentId = s.StudentId,
                                           StudentName = s.StudentName
                                       })
                          .ToList(); 
}
```

This joins the 2 tables together and I don't need the year in this instance, so it's a useless join.

I tried using the Linq to query syntax to be more explicit:

```
(from students in context.Students  
 select new Student {
    StudentId = students.StudentId,
    StudentName = students.StudentName
  }).ToList();
```

I thought this might query the `yearId`, but it is still performing a join on the 2 tables.

Comment: How do you know EF is including the related table by default?  Any SQL Trace logs to show?  EF generally only includes other tables if you mentioned them in your code and even then only on-demand.

Comment: ...the bigger question is why you are cloning existing entries.  Now you have two of everything; with the **same ID**!

Comment: What do you mean im cloning?How should i query the entries?

Comment: There is no need for the `.Select(s => new Student ` nor `select new Student`.  You already _have an object_ and is the essence of ORMs.  This isn't old-school ADO.NET with it's tabular approach to things.

Comment: And how should i query then?

Answer (score 1):

I realized it wasn't joining the tables if i didn't refer to the year property.
Ìf i used the year in the query then it would join the two tables together.

Just had to turn on sql logs to better see what's happening.